# How to develop a plugin for Spark in a Filesystem?

Tags: java, apache-spark, filesystems

I am totally new to this. So here is the thing. I want to develop a plugin for Spark in a certain Filesystem. Generally speaking, what do I need to know? And what do I have to start with?

Comment: Basically need to extend this and implement the abstract methods https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java

Comment: Why is that a hadoop class that you're indicating to extend. Doesn't suppose to be Spark?

Comment: Spark does not have its own file system mechanism but it reuses the hadoop system

Comment: So what I understood is that I have to build my own implementation of the Hadoop Filesystem that supports the filesystem I intend to work with (to replace HDFS) and then I'm done, right?